# Reliable way to ensure a Go channel does not block

Tags: go, channel, lock-free

I'm looking for a reliable to way to make sure an empty channel in Go does not block my execution. I have to iterate through a number of channels in a particular order (kind of priorities), and once I find one with items in it, read one.

Currently I do something in a similar way:

```
if len(myChannel) > 0 {
    // Possible issue here: length could have changed to 0 making this blocking
    elm := <- myChannel
    return elm
}
```

In theory this could result into too-long of waiting, while a different channel might have an item which is ready to be "served".

Any suggestions on how to improve? I could use a mutex in the channel, but it feels like there's a better solution although I'm not sure how.

Comment: Why not use a ``select`` statement?

Comment: How would you write such a statement in an dynamical way (e.g. iterate an array of channels)?

Comment: In general, when multiple go routines write into these channels, it's not possible to do what you want. Between the check if the channel has space left and the send operation to that channel, somebody else might have put something in the channel, causing it to block.

Comment: @FUZxxl so that would mean a mutex per channel would be the only real solution?

Comment: @RobinUS2 Or one mutex for all channels... As I said, that depends on your use case. If there is only one Go routine that writes into the channels, you don't need that.

Comment: Rather than have a dynamic array of channels, have a single channel and get your goroutines to write to the same one.  You are looking for the "fan-in" concurrency pattern.  See: http://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Comment: @dyoo As far as I'm aware of that won't work, as I have to read the channels in a certain priority. If we all write to the same channel there will be a certain order of processing, but that won't account for the priority. Right?

Comment: The use of select has no built-in notion of priority: if multiple cases succeed, we get a pseudo-randomly chosen one.  See Point 2 in:  http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements

Comment: By @BalthazarRouberol's "why not use a `select`" I took that not as use a select across all channels, but a select with a default clause to avoid blocking on a single channel. This is the [standard way in Go to not block when reading a channel](https://play.golang.org/p/c-l7y6veHf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `reflect.Select` function that might do what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a, b, c := make(chan int), make(chan int), make(chan int)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        a <- 1
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        b <- 2
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        c <- 3
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        chosen, recv, ok := reflect.Select([]reflect.SelectCase{
            reflect.SelectCase{
                Dir:  reflect.SelectRecv,
                Chan: reflect.ValueOf(a),
            },
            reflect.SelectCase{
                Dir:  reflect.SelectRecv,
                Chan: reflect.ValueOf(b),
            },
            reflect.SelectCase{
                Dir:  reflect.SelectRecv,
                Chan: reflect.ValueOf(c),
            },
        })
        if ok {
            fmt.Printf("Got value %d from %d\n", recv.Interface().(int), chosen)
        }
    }
}
```

[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/Rn37No912E)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this really answers the question "Is there a reliable way to ensure a Go channel does not block".   In the OP's use case, it's OK if a recv blocks /so long as no other channel in the set would not block/, and that's what the accepted solution implements.  This is different from "ensure the recv does not block", and I see no way around the fundamental limitation of the race condition OP points out.

Comment: Are you not aware of `select` with a `default:` case? That allows non-blocking channel operations. (e.g. read or not without any race).