# Is there a reliable way to ensure a Go channel does not block on read?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, go

This is a followup to [a previous thread with a similar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687114/reliable-way-to-ensure-a-go-channel-does-not-block).

It has an accepted answer, but that answer does not really answer the question.   From that thread, here is the use-case:

```
if len(myChannel) > 0 {
   // Possible issue here: length could have changed to 0 making this blocking
   elm := <- myChannel
   return elm
 }
```

The OP calls it a "Possible issue", but it's a Definite Issue:  a race condition in which another consumer may have pulled a value from the channel between the evaluation of the if condition and execution of the two statements.

Now, we are told the Go Way is to favor channels over mutex, but here it seems we can not acheive even basic non-blocking read (by polling length and reading atomically) without pairing a mutex and a channel together, and using our new concurrency data type instead of a channel.

Can that be right?  Is there really no way to reliably ensure a recv does not block by checking ahead for space?  (Compare with BlockingQueue.poll() in Java, or similar facilities in other queue-based messaging IPC facilities...)

Comment: (The accepted answer in the previous post solves OP's specific use case - sidestepping the issue by allowing the race condition to strike in specific circumstance.  Therefore, it is useful to him but does not literally answer his question.   My question here is for the literal answer to his question.  Please note the difference and see my comment there before flagging dup)

Comment: From your question and link, it looks like you're putting real effort in, so may be worth working through the Tour (which covers default select at http://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6), [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) (section "Select statements" covers this), or [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) (where this comes up in an example in the section headed "A leaky buffer").

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at those, thanks.  I kind of "dumbed down" my use case in these couple of posts such that the answers were correct but not directly useful.   What I'm really trying to do might be described as "transparent all-or-nothing channel multiplexing", ie. fan-outs that only send to any receivers if they can all receive.   I've accomplished what I needed to combining the default case thing (yes, I'm new to Go! :p ) with the reflect version of Select, and having a weird kind of "pump" goroutine collecting from input and sending to output...

Comment: There's also a lot on concurrency specifically in the [Go Concurrency Patterns](https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1) and [Concurrency is not parallelism](http://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide) talks. (That wasn't in response to your last comment, started writing before I saw it.)

Comment: A question describing your use case for checking the blocking status of a set of channels might shake out an alternative approach. Maybe you want a `WaitGroup` for waiting until all workers are ready, or maybe there's just an entirely different way to approach the overall problem that fits more easily with what Go provides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what default cases in `select` are for:

```
var elm myType
select {
case elm = <-myChannel:
default:
}
return elm
```

This assigns `elm` if it can, and otherwise returns a zero value. See "A leaky buffer" from [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) for a somewhat more extensive example.

Answer (score 2):

Rob Napier's answer is correct.

However, you are possibly trying too hard to achieve non-blocking behaviour, assuming that it is an anti-pattern.

With Go, you *don't* have to worry about blocking. Go ahead, block without guilt. It can make code much easier to write, especially when dealing with i/o.

CSP allows you to design data-driven concurrent programs that can scale very well (because of not using mutexes too much). Small groups of goroutines communicating via channels can behave like a component of a larger system; these components (also communicating via channels) can be grouped into larger components; this pattern repeats at increasing scales.

Conventionally, people start with sequential code and then try to add concurrency by adding goroutines, channels, mutexes etc. As an exercise, try something different: try designing a system to be *maximally concurrent* - use goroutines and channels as deeply as you possibly can. You might be unimpressed with the performance you achieve ... so then perhaps try to consider how to improve it by *combining* (rather than *dividing*) blocks, reducing the total number of goroutines and so achieving a more optimal concurrency.